# I am not able to work with Groovy JMeter function the value returned by MD5 function is not matching the standard values

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter

1. Value returned from JMeter JSR223 Sampler using **.md5()** function.

[image]

2. MD5 value for same payload generated on Standard website

[image]

I think I am not able to parse it properly? Can someone please tell me where the problem is and how to fix it.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: `{\n    \"contact\":\"9876543210\"\n}` as input for Groovy, produces the same hash as in https://coding.tools/md5

Comment: @ShaharT Yes. So how should I convert the plain input shown in question into formatted input that you have asked? Any other function for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use something simple like `foo` you will see that your "Standard website" and JSR223 PreProcessor are generating the same value.

The question is how does your "Standard website" handle line [breaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_break) and other non-printable characters like [whitespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) or [tabs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key#Tab_characters)

So my expectation is that you should be asking your API developers regarding the request format, my expectation is that JMeter's checksum is correct.

You can look [here](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/e6ce56fc27e7640664946eb1a99bdee6fb63547e/src/main/java/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/EncodingGroovyMethods.java#L377) for Groovy's implementation

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: MD5 function working fine and the output is same as standard website. The only thing I need to do is put the request in single line :)